# Subtotal formula with unknown amount of rows in a column when the range is based on a text in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a subtotal column that starts in cell I11 but I don't know the amount of rows as it will change each time.  At the end of the column are multiply functions based on the subtotal.

I am trying to create a macro that will count the amount of rows starting at I11 and will go until the value in column F equals "Value of Work Done"

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Total_Amount()
'New_Entry Macro

 Dim PPC1 As Worksheet
 Dim rowNo As Integer
 rowNo = ActiveCell.Row

 If PPC1.Range("F11:F").Value = "VALUE OF WORK DONE" Then

    With Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
        .Offset(1).Formula = "=SUM(I11:" & .Address(0, 0) & ")"
    End With
 End If

End Sub
```

The answer still comes up at the end of the column instead of beside "Value of Work Done"

```
 Sub Total_Amount()
 'New_Entry Macro

 Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim lRow As Long
 Dim lLast As Long

 Set ws = Worksheets("PPC 1")
 Row = 11

Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If ws.Range("F" & lRow).Value = "Value of Work Done" Then
        lLast = lRow
        Exit Do
    End If
    lRow = lRow + 1
Loop

ws.Range("I" & lRow + 1).Formula = Application.Sum("I11:I" & lLast)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ws as excel.worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lLast as Long

Set ws = Worksheets("PPC 1")
lRow = 11

Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count
    If ws.Range("F" & lRow).Value = "Value of Work Done" then
        lLast = lRow
        Exit do
    End if
lRow = lRow + 1
Loop
```

Then write the formula to whatever column you want

```
ws.Range("I" & lLast).Formula = Application.Sum("I11:I" & lLast)
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew but it is still putting the value at the end of the column not beside Value of Work Done and the sum formula keeps throwing errors I changed it to:

 Sub Total_Amount()
'New_Entry Macro

Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lLast As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("PPC 1")
lRow = 11

Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If ws.Range("F" & lRow).Value = "Value of Work Done" Then
        lLast = lRow
        Exit Do
    End If
lRow = lRow + 1
Loop

ws.Range("I" & lRow + 1).Formula = Application.Sum("I11:I" & lLast)

End Sub

Comment: @Jody edit the question instead of writing it here in the comments, as it makes it unreadable. You can then notify Matthew it changed by using the comments. Also, look at how I edited your code in your question to put it in the grey rectangle. While submitting your questions/answers, select the part which is code and click 'code sample' in the editing tab up top.

Comment: Thanks David - will do

Comment: @Jody Patterson.  I have updated the answer with your changes. Are there any remaining issues?